# How to add leaflet-measure-path addon to Leaflet.Editable?

Tags: leaflet

I want to see a measures, generated by [leaflet-measure-path](https://github.com/ProminentEdge/leaflet-measure-path) on polylines, dynamically created via [Leaflet.Editable](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Editable) 's control.
How do I do it most correctly?

Comment: Have you already seen [this example](https://prominentedge.com/leaflet-measure-path/)?

Comment: Yes, of course. This example about exists polylines, not created by Leaflet.Editable control.